# ubuntu vs windows adobe products

Tags: pdf, photoshop, adobe-acrobat

Considering ditching windows 10 altogether.. 
But one of my main concerns is losing adobe acrobat. 
What is the best free and paid pdf editors for ubuntu?
Need to be able text.
Also is there anything that can compete with photoshop?

Comment: Run the following command for a list of packages available through apt-get (copy/paste all one command): `apt-cache search pdf | egrep 'manipulation|convert|export|edit|generate|create|modify|modif|cube'`

Comment: photoshop competitors are actually two different applications depending on the file type: gimp and inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

The link above has a suggestion for PDF editors.

I used photoshop for years.  For now I use [gimp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gimp&searchon=names).  As far as I can see all the features I even needed are done just as easy in Gimp.  Photopshop wasn't a bad learning curb.  But I consider Gimp and upgrade over photoshop.